# generalize maybe and either functions in haskell

Tags: generics, haskell

Is there a function in haskell that generalizes the maybe and either functions?

For instance, I am imagining a function like this:

```hs
generalizedFunc :: SOMETHING m => b -> (a -> b) -> m a -> b
generalizedFunc valForError f value = ...
```

Working with it in ghci would look like this:

```hs
> generalizedFunc "bye" (\_ -> "hello") (Just 3)
"hello"
> generalizedFunc "bye" (\_ -> "hello") Nothing
"bye"
> generalizedFunc "bye" (\_ -> "hello") (Right 3)
"hello"
> generalizedFunc "bye" (\_ -> "hello") (Left "error")
"bye"
```

*note: Tom Ellis makes a good point that this is not a generalization of Either, but rather a specialization.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. What you're looking for is [`Data.Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html). It generalizes `foldr` (for lists) to any algebraic data type:

```hs
Data.List.foldr     :: (a -> b -> b) -> b     ->   []       a -> b
maybe               :: b -> (a -> b)          ->   Maybe    a -> b
either              :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c)   ->   Either a b -> c
---
Data.Foldable.foldr :: Foldable t
                    => (a -> b -> b) -> b     ->   t        a -> b
```

Your code would change from `generalizedFunc "bye" (\_ -> "hello")` to `foldr (\_ _ -> "hello") "bye"`. Make sure you tell the compiler that you mean the `foldr` from `Data.Foldable`; see the documentation of the module.

Unfortunately, the `Foldable (Either a)` instance might be missing for your version of GHC, but writing one yourself should be relatively easy.

Comment: `Data.Foldable` really just provides a mapping from other data types to `[]`. [`Data.Functor.Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-4.0/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html) provides a real generalization of `foldr`, named `cata`.

Comment: @Carl: yes, in a way. `foldMap` is a better way of thinking about it. But for most applications, `Data.Foldable` (or `Data.Traversable`) suffices. The complaint "you shouldn't need to be a category theory expert to use Haskell" refers *directly* to the likes of `Data.Functor.Foldable`; it *looks* like a terribly cumbersome library to use, made worse by the lack of proper documentation.

Comment: @Carl: Would you be able to show an example of using cata to write my original example?  I didn't understand the types.

Comment: @illabout I wrote up [an example of using `cata`](http://lpaste.net/103930), and it mostly shows why the `recursion-schemes` package isn't used much in the real world. It does succeed in abstracting over catamorphisms, but it's an incredibly painful thing to work with unless all your data types are already defined as fixed points and all your logic is expressed in algebras.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is a little bit of self promotion but I'll post it because it's very relevant.

I wrote a small library a while back called [generic-church](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-church). This exports a single type class with two functions. To use it, simply do something like

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
import GHC.Generics
import Data.Church

data Nat = Z | S Nat

instance ChurchRep Nat
```

Notice that `Nat` need not be a functor as with `Foldable`.

We can then fire up GHCi and do something like

```
*> (toChurch Z) 'a' (const 'b')
  'a'
*> (toChurch $ S Z) 'a' (const 'b')
  'b'
```

And unlike `foldr` you can automagically turn a church representation back into a concrete data type

```
*> fromChurch (\a b -> a) :: Nat
  Z
*> fromChurch (a b -> b Z) :: Nat
  S Z
```

Now one obvious downside as compared to catamorphisms/folds is that `generic-church` currently handles recursive data types in a slightly naive way (though I'm looking to fix this Real Soon Now). Namely, it treats any recursive type as though it where unfolded one level in it's church representation, so the church representation of `Nat` is

```
type Nat' = forall c. c -> (Nat -> c) -> c
```

#### Edit, your `generalFunc`

Here's the code to write your `generalFunc` in a manner which actually generalizes `maybe`. I need a function `toChurchP` which is in generic-church-0.2 uploaded about 5 minutes prior to me typing this. If you want to run this code be sure to use `cabal update` :)

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, TypeFamilies, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module So where
import Data.Church
import GHC.Generics
import Data.Proxy

-- Generalize of const. Allows us to use more than just Either
-- for gmaybe
class GConst a r where
  gconst :: r -> a
instance GConst r' r => GConst (a -> r') r where
  gconst r = const (gconst r)
instance GConst r r where
  gconst = id

gfail :: forall a e s e' r. 
          (ChurchRep a, GConst e' e, Church a r ~ (e' -> s -> r)) =>
           e -> s -> a -> r
gfail e s a = toChurchP (Proxy :: Proxy r) a (gconst e :: e') s
```

This depends on the that `gconst` to swallow all arguments given to the failure result, `e`. A clever definition should allow something like

```
> gfail id (const 'a') $ Left 'b'
  'b'
```

But my current formulation would require `-XIncoherentInstances` (eek!). I'll hopefully update with a version that would actually generalize both `either` and `maybe`.

As it is this is still kinda nifty.

```
*So> gfail True id (Just False)
False
*So> gfail True (id :: Bool -> Bool) Nothing
True
*So> gfail 'a' (const 'b') (Left ())
'a'
*So> gfail 'a' (const 'b') (Right ())
'b'
*So> :set -XDeriveGeneric
*So> data MyMaybe = Fail | Yay Int deriving (Show, Generic)
*So> instance ChurchRep MyMaybe
*So> gfail 'a' (const 'b') (Yay 1)
'b'
```

Comment: This sounds really cool, but due to my lack of experience with Haskell (and category theory), I'm having trouble seeing how this relates to the maybe and either methods.  Would you be able to rewrite my original example `generalizedFunc` using your library?